# Cannot get MVC 5 Attribute Routing to work for the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I cannot get MVC 5 Attribute Routing to work for the Controller. I'm getting a 404 and I'm really not sure what I am missing. I have looked up a heap of examples online and as far as I can see I have followed them 100%

I would like a controller called 'CustomerServicePolicyController' to work against the route http://[site]/customer-service-policy/.

I'm using MVC 5. Here's what I have done:

1. Opened up RouteConfig.cs

Modified it to the following:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //enabling attribute routing
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //convention-based routing
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           namespaces: new[] { "TTTA.Controllers" }
               );
    }
```

2. Created a Controller called CustomerServicePolicyController.cs

Ensured it was as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TTTA.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("customer-service-policy")]
    [Route("{action=index}")] //default action 
    public class CustomerServicePolicyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Ensured my View folder was there and named appropriately as "CustomerServicePolicy". Note, when this didn't work I also tried renaming this folder to "customer-service-policy" but same 404!
4. Ensured I had an index.cshtml file in the View folder.

I thought that should do it but I'm just getting the 404 each time when I visit http://[site]/customer-service-policy/.

I can confirm that http://[site]/CustomerServicePolicy/ also no longer works but does work again if I remove the attributes above the Controller declaration.

What am I missing? Something obvious I bet...

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for web and the incumbent web server - IIS Express.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks all good. Could not see any reason why it would not work? In fact your code works fine in my machine. Is the issue only with the Attribute routing? If you remove Route attributes and govern route only from Route config does it work?

Comment: Hi there. Many thanks @Sarvesh. Yes, if I remove the Route attributes all works fine with the default routing. Very confused...